# How to get Project.Web BaseDirectory On Project.Test?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I am running my test specs on Project.Test and I can find this project directory :

```
var path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

But I want to find Project.Web directory on Test project , I tried like this example but it doesn't work :(

```
BaseDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(s => s.GetType().Namespace.ToLower() == "system.web.mvc").Single().Location;
```

Do you have any Ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with this code :

```
string webDir = ((FileSystemInfo)(Directory.GetParent(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory).Parent.Parent.GetDirectories("Project.Web", SearchOption.AllDirectories)[0])).FullName;
```